# Joomla 4 - 404 pages always redirects to the homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, joomla

In my Joomla 4 site I'm trying to create redirects for old URL like for example:

Old url: `https://www.example.com/oldpage`
New url: `https://www.example.com/newpage`

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  (C) 2005 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of Apache mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by
# your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to
# set it here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymlinks
#Options -Indexes

## No directory listings
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    #IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Suppress mime type detection in browsers for unknown types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
##
# Disable Federated Learning of Cohorts (FLoC)
# If you uncomment the below directive you have to allow this technology in the
# Global Configuration of Joomla. Read more about this in the Post-Installation
# message in the backend.
##
# Header always set Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"
</IfModule>

## Protect against certain cross-origin requests. More information can be found here:
## https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)
## https://web.dev/why-coop-coep/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   Header always set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "same-origin"
#   Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp"
#</IfModule>

## Disable inline JavaScript when directly opening SVG files or embedding them with the object-tag
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none'"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_rewrite module is enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
    # If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
    # below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
    # This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
    #
    # Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
    # Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    # Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    # Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
    #
    ## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

    ## Begin - Custom redirects
    #
    # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
    # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
    # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
    #
    ## End - Custom redirects

    ##
    # Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
    # is not directly related to physical file paths.
    # Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
    ##

    RewriteBase /blog/

    ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
    #
    # PHP FastCGI fix for HTTP Authorization, required for the API application
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # -- SEF URLs for the API application
    # If the requested path starts with /api, the file is not /api/index.php
    # and the request has not already been internally rewritten to the
    # api/index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/index\.php
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the /api/index.php script
    RewriteRule .* api/index.php [L]
    # -- SEF URLs for the public frontend application
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    #
    ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
</IfModule>

## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_rewrite module is disabled
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When Apache mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect
        # of the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_headers module is enabled.
## This section will check if a .gz file exists and if so will stream it
##     directly or fallback to gzip any asset on the fly
## If your site starts to look strange after enabling this, and you see
##     ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in your browser console network tab,
##     then your server is already gzipping css and js files and you don't need this
##     block enabled in your .htaccess
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.css" "$1\.css\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.js" "$1\.js\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
        # Serve correct encoding type.
        Header append Content-Encoding gzip

        # Force proxies to cache gzipped &
        # non-gzipped css/js files separately.
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But this doesn't work because the old link is not a 404 page and always redirects to the homepage. All 404 pages redirect to the homepage.
How can I remove the reiderect for all 404 pages to homepage?
If the old URL doesn't become a 404 page the redirect will never work...

P.S. My website is with Astroid framework and SP Page Builder component for the homepage!

Comment: Please share your htaccess file in the question.

Comment: I shared my htaccess file man!

Comment: I added details for my website!

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Where have you put the redirects for the "old" to "new" URLs? I can't see anything in the code you've posted?

Comment: "How can I remove the reiderect for all 404 pages to homepage?" - how does that help if the "old link is not a 404 page" in the first place? But if the old URL is not a 404 page (so is an existing page on the new site) then you presumably cannot redirect it, otherwise the page is not accessible?!

Comment: The reditect Is setted to plugin of Joomla but not work!

Comment: No suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Joomla plugin, you could implement these redirects in `.htaccess` instead. These are then processed *before* Joomla/PHP is processed. These directives would need to go in the `# Begin - Custom redirects` section as indicated in the `.htaccess` file you've posted.

For example:

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#

RewriteRule ^oldpage$ /newpage [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^subfolder/oldpage/$ /subfolder/newpage/ [R=301,L]

## End - Custom redirects
```

The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive is a regex that matches the requested URL-path only. Note that the URL matched does not start with a slash. Any query string is passed through to the target URL by default. If this is not required then include the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag as well. ie. `[QSD,R=301,L]`.

NB: Test first with `R=302` (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: I tried man in this way ---> RewriteRule ^/subfolder/oldpage/$ /subfolder/newpage/ [R=302,L] but not work. When I try to throw the address www.example.com/subfolder/oldpage return ever in homepage...

Comment: @Jackom As in my example above, there is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. So, that should be `RewriteRule ^subfolder/oldpage/$ /subfolder/newpage/ [R=302,L]` instead. (I've updated my answer to explicitly state that.)

Comment: @Jackom Also, be mindful of trailing slashes. If you need to match URLs both with and without a trailing slash then make the trailing slash optional in the regex. eg. `RewriteRule ^oldpage/?$ /newpage/ [R=301,L]`